# Reading user privileges on a PDF, things like password, signature etc?

Tags: php, perl, file, pdf

I need to write a tool which is able to access a pdf file and read what all feature/user privileges are active on the document. I plant to take the development in 2 stages.
First stage: 
Determine what all features/user privileges are active on the document. i.e. detecting if any of the following are enabled and what is their type.
Password, Digital Signatures, Reader Extensions, Certificate security & Policy.

I have seen PDF for PHP but this does not look like it has the features i require. What package / language is best suited for this kind of tool ?

I am comfortable working in C, C++, Perl, PHP, Python or Java.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Perl's [CAM::PDF](https://metacpan.org/module/CAM%3a%3aPDF). I believe it can do at least some of the things you want.